# Magento calling parent function not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a plugin: Simple Configurable Products. I've upgraded to 1.8.1 but have an issue with showing the price - it stops rendering the page.

I have found the line that's causing the issue:

```
parent::_toHtml();
```

The class that is calling that is as follows:

```
class OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
{
    public function _toHtml() {
       // Do some stuff
       return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

So as I see it, the parent class should be: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price. And the line that calls this should simply call the function _toHtml(). Taking this line out means it works, but returns no price. Ideally I need it to render the default/base price html.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is an if condition ON Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
where if condition holds true it returns empty

"if (!$this->getProduct() || $this->getProduct()->getCanShowPrice() === false)"

could you make sure the condition doesnt hold true

Comment: @teja_korlapati Yes, that condition is false and it passes it to run: return parent::_toHtml(); on that function...

Comment: post your question here [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)
the site is dedicated to magento.You might find some help!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this:

```
class OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
        extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price {

    public function _toHtml() {
        // Do some stuff
        return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Call the object by name instead of by `parent::_toHtml()`